# Using git checkout I'm checking out branch, how to reverse this operation?

Tags: git

After I checked out git branch from remote repository, it now is displayed in result of `git branch` command. I'm not working on that branch anymore so I'd like it to not be listed. Is there a way to do so?

**EDIT** I don't want to delete that branch anyhow, I just want to `git branch` not display it. But, well, if in the future I will need it again, I could make `git checkout` and see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git branch -d my_branch
```

will delete only the local branch, *not* the remote.  So if you want to pull it again at some later date, you can.

Comment: what if I make git push, will it remove branch on remote repo?

Comment: No.  Firstly, once you delete your local branch, you can't BE on that branch any more, so there's no chance that any action that applies to the "current branch" could *accidentally* apply to that remote branch.  Secondly, in order to remove that remote branch, you'd need to run (*don't do this!*) either `git push origin :my_branch` (note the colon in front of the branch name) or `git push origin --delete my_branch`.

Answer (score 1):

to delete branch locally

```
git branch -d <name_of_your_new_branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the branch you wish to hide from `git branch` output into something **not** under `refs/heads` like this

```
 git update-ref refs/hidden/branch_name branch_name 
 git branch -D branch_name
```